# Download Excel On Link Button click in Telerik RadGrid

Tags: asp.net, gridview, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a Telerik RadGrid inside an Update Panel. One of the columns in the RadGrid has link buttons. I would like to export an excel file when the button is clicked. 
I have written the code and when I click on the linkButton, the page refreshes and the download does not happen. I have tried using anchor tag instead of the link button but it didnt work.

My ASP.net code is here

```
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel runat="server" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
                                <telerik:RadGrid ID="GridViewAllRequests" runat="server" CssClass="ms-listviewtable" border="0" BorderStyle="None" HeaderStyle-BorderStyle="None" CellPadding="4" GridLines="None" Width="100%"
                                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" MasterTableView-ShowFooter="false" ShowStatusBar="false"
                                    AllowPaging="True" PageSize="25" AllowSorting="true" MasterTableView-AllowMultiColumnSorting="true" EnableLinqExpressions="false"
                                    ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" ShowFooter="false" DataSourceID="LinqDsGridViewAllRequests" OnItemCreated="RadGrid_ItemCreated" On>
                                    <GroupingSettings CaseSensitive="false"></GroupingSettings>
                                    <MasterTableView DataSourceID="LinqDsGridViewAllRequests" DataKeyNames="RequestName" AutoGenerateColumns="false" PagerStyle-ShowPagerText="false" PagerStyle-Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Blue" ShowFooter="false">
                                        <Columns>
                                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="RequestName" HeaderText="Request Name" UniqueName="RequestName" HeaderStyle-CssClass="ms-vh2"
                                                SortExpression="RequestName">

                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lblRequestName"   ForeColor="Blue" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("RequestName") %>' CommandName="onclick" OnCommand="RequestNameLinkButton_Click" runat ="server" Text='<%# Eval("RequestName") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="ms-vh2" />
                                                <ItemStyle CssClass="talCell4Grid" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" />
                                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

In the code, lblRequestName is the LinkButton that I want to use for downloading excel.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `if (!IsPostBack)` wrap all code in `Page_Load` function, it can prevent page reload when you click the button.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //some code about page load
    }
}
```

Comment: I will have to change a lot of code in this case. Is there a way that only link button does not reload page and causes excel download

Comment: there is another way, you can use jquery ajax, it won't trigger page load, but it's more complex than adding `if (!IsPostBack)`

Comment: Also I would like to do postback in case other controls are clicked, so its better to disable page load for just one link button

Comment: Add an ajax on the grid the grid to stop the page reload.

<telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="GridViewAllRequests">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="GridViewAllRequests" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>